Is the Newtonian gravitational force equation $F = GMm/r^2$ an approximation, even in strictly Newtonian terms?
According to Wikipedia the acceleration of small mass due to the gravitational attraction of a larger mass is $$a = \frac{G(M + m)}{r^2}.$$ This implies that the force acting on $m$ should be $$F = ma = m \times G(M + m) $$ $$F = \frac{G(Mm +m^2)}{r^2} $$
If for example if $m =$ 0.001$M$ such that $m$ is a small fraction of $M$, the above equation could be written as :
$$F = \frac{G(Mm + (0.001M)^2)}{r^2} = \frac{G(Mm + 0.000001M)}{r^2}$$
it seems that because when $m$ is much smaller than $M$ the $m^2$ term becomes negligible and is discarded to give us the much more well known formula $ F = GMm/r^2$, meaning the well known formula is an approximation even without considering general relativity and is not accurate where $m$ is a significant fraction of $M$. Is that the case?

Where in Wikipedia is that first equation written? I think there is a problem there

The equation with the addition that you are referring to, applies only when you upgrade to using reduced mass. Namely, $Mm=(M+m)\mu$. You are simply totally misunderstanding what it is saying.

@Mauricio It is my interpretation of combining the equation labelled (1) and the following equation, in the "Simplified two body problem" section .

@naturallyInconsistent That's quite possible

@kdp it seems that it is your interpretation of equation 1 that is wrong. Equation 1 seems to refer to the gravitational acceleration of a given mass to another of mass $M+m$

The wikipedia article you cite derives this expression for acceleration ($a = G(M + m) / r^2)$ from Newton's law, so I am not sure how this expression can be more fundamental.
Also, it is the expression for the acceleration of the displacement between two bodies and is not related to the force acting on the smaller (or the larger body).

Possible duplicates: Don't heavier objects actually fall faster because they exert their own gravity? and links therein.

Related, but not identical.

The link says:
"Dividing by their respective masses and subtracting the second equation from the first yields the equation of motion for the acceleration of the first object with respect to the second"
That is, in an inertial frame:
$$ a \equiv \frac{d^2r}{dt^2} = F/m = G\frac{M}{r^2} $$
but the formula you give is for:
$$\frac{d^2(r-R)}{dt^2} = G\frac{M+m}{(R-r)^2}$$
where $r$ ($R$) is the position of $m$ ($M$).
So we can kind of work backwards. With $r$ and $R$ being affine points in an inertial frame:
$$ \ddot R = \frac 1 M G \frac{Mm}{(R-r)^2} = G \frac{m}{(R-r)^2}$$
$$ \ddot r = \frac 1 m G \frac{Mm}{(R-r)^2} = G \frac{M}{(R-r)^2}$$
so
$$ \ddot r - \ddot R =  G \frac{M+m}{(R-r)^2} $$
where I flipped the sign since the forces are equal and opposite .

The comments to OP seem very confused. The issue, as @JEB shows here is that the equation given by OP is for the relative acceleration of the two bodies, not relative to the inertial frame.
